# ESMTP Postfix Server - prevent overriding Message-ID

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, messageid

in our CRM-System I have to identify every incoming E-Mail by the Message-ID, with that ID I can check if I already have a related E-Mail in the System. 
Now, it seems that my Postfix Server every time overrides my generated Message-ID. 
Is there any configuration to prevent the server overriding the Message-ID ?

I tested it with a google Account and the Google Server is not overriding the ID.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Postfix ONLY adds a message-id header when there's none.
Without seeing

```
postconf -n
```

output it's hard to tell.

There might be a **header_checks** entry that strips the Message-Id using a regular expression, but one wouldn't usually forget such a thing.